# Python/Selenium script timeout exception when trying to click a button

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm struggling a little bit with what should be a simple Python/Selenium script.

So all i want to do is to to have an automated way of clicking a button on a webpage which then downloads the CSV file behind the button click.

The script is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import time

custom_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
custom_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})

service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=custom_options)

url = "https://data.gov.il/dataset/aircraft_data_il/resource/bc00ed41-75d0-4d0f-9eca-3cd0a2c332cc?fbclid=IwAR0ECd4VNpZ8FRLZSswOw-xM2EVpEeosJvxmhrYDt2bwvYSe1myQ9McCQ9g"

custom_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
custom_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
custom_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
custom_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
custom_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
custom_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
custom_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
custom_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
custom_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

driver.get(url)

download_button_xpath = "//*[@id='content']/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30) # Increase wait time if necessary
download_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, download_button_xpath)))

download_button.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()

print("CSV file downloaded successfully!")
```

The problem i'm getting is some form of timeout exception as shown below. I'm pretty sure that the The XPath is correct and i can't see how the button isn't loaded within the specified wait time.

I also tried a different approach to locate the download button by searching for the button using its attributes but i got the same timeout exception

```
line 40, in <module>
    download_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, download_button_xpath)))
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009EDCE3+50899]
    (No symbol) [0x0097E111]
    (No symbol) [0x00885588]
    (No symbol) [0x008B08F9]
    (No symbol) [0x008B0AFB]
    (No symbol) [0x008DF902]
    (No symbol) [0x008CB944]
    (No symbol) [0x008DE01C]
    (No symbol) [0x008CB6F6]
    (No symbol) [0x008A7708]
    (No symbol) [0x008A886D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C53EAE+2566302]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C892B1+2784417]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C8327C+2759788]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A85740+672048]
    (No symbol) [0x00988872]
    (No symbol) [0x009841C8]
    (No symbol) [0x009842AB]
    (No symbol) [0x009771B7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76146B89+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x774B8F9F+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x774B8F6D+1165]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it seems to throw a TimeoutException, even though the button seems to be there, but an alternative approach would be to go to the url that the `<a>` element is trying to forward you to so the file download starts.
This code should work:

```py
download_button_xpath = "//*[@id='content']/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button/a" # Get a element
a_src = download_button_xpath.get_attribute('src') # Get it's src attribute

driver.get('https://data.gov.il' + a_src) # Go to the url
```

Comment: Thank you. I  think that the other issue that i was having was that the website was detecting Selenium so i added the following lines:

```custom_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
custom_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)```

which seemed to get around the issue and successfully downloaded the file.